# Implement a function "decorator" in C that reverts the result of the original function

Tags: c

Is it possible to implement a function in C that takes a function pointer `fp1` and returns another function pointer `fp2`, so that whenever `*fp1` returns value `x` on a list of arguments, `*fp2` would return `-x` on the same list of arguments?

Let's say

```c
typedef int CompareFunc(const void *, const void *);
```

We would like to have a reverter that always reverses the comparison result from `-1, 0, 1` to `1, 0, -1`.

In other words, is it possible to do

```c
CompareFunc *rev(CompareFunc *fp)
{
  //...
}
```

so that, for example,

```c
qsort(arr, num, size, rev(comp));
```

would always give the opposite sorting result of

```
qsort(arr, num, size, comp);
```

---

I hope I am not making people angry by comparing it with some other languages. So in Python this could be done with

```py
def rev(func):
  def decorated(a, b):
    return -func(a, b)
  return decorated
```

and in C++ this carries some resemblance to the `std::not_fn`, though that one returns the negation.

---

In general, I am wondering about the standard / common practice in C to achieve this.

Comment: Unlike in C++, in C functions/functors are always stateless. You have nowhere to store the address of the original function, except in a global (possibly `thread_local`) variable.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the insight `Unlike in C++, in C functions/functors are always stateless` which I think is the key to understanding the problem. Could you please talk a little bit more about this C vs C++ difference, or give some reference on it?

Comment: I don't have much to add. C++ solutions would either use a class that stores a pointer to the original function, with overloaded `operator()` (the closest C alternative uses a global variable to store the pointer, see KamilCuk's answer). Or a template that generates the inverted function (the closest C alternative uses macros, see Picaud Vincent's answer).

Comment: I see. Just want to clarify, for a normal C++ function like `void foo(int);` (neither a functor that overloads `operator()` nor a lambda), it has nothing different in terms of being stateful/stateless when compared with a C function, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Why can't you simply call qsort twice with different callback functions? That's how it's supposed do be done and it easily solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to do

No (without [compiler extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C_(non-standard_extension))).

> I am wondering about the standard / common practice in C to achieve this.

The common practice is to pass *user context* to some function using a `void*` argument, like in `thrd_create(..., void *arg);` or `pthread_create(...., void *arg)` or `fopencookie(void *cookie, ...)` or `pthread_cleanup_push(..., void *arg)` or `on_exit(..., void *arg)` etc. Maybe we will see the day when `qsort_r` will be integrated to the standard:

```
struct rev_s {
     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void*);
     void *arg;
};
int rev(const void*a, const void *b, void *arg) {
    const struct rev_s *ctx = arg;
    return - ctx->compar(a, b, ctx->arg);
}

int main() {
   qsort_r(arr, num, size, rev, &(struct rev_s){ comp });
}
```

With `qsort` function to be *standard compliant*, you would use a global variable to pass the "context" - ie `struct rev_s`, making the function non-reentrant:

```
// global variable instead of argument
int (*rev_compar)(const void *, const void *);
int rev(const void*a, const void *b) {
    return - rev_compar(a, b);
}

int main() {
   // initialize global variable -> spagetti code smell
   rev_compar = &comp;
   qsort(arr, num, size, rev);
}
```

Comment: You can make `rev_compar` `_Thread_local` to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the code examples! I am accepting your answer. Just a minor point: you introduced a local variable `rev` that has the same name as the function `rev` that it is in. While that's legal and the names are conceptually related, it did cause a little confusion to me : )

Answer (score 1):

You still can use a macro, but yes it is cheating :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = {40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25};

int
compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

#define CREATE_REVERSE(fname) \
  int fname##_reverse(const void* a, const void* b) { return fname(b, a); }

CREATE_REVERSE(compare)
  
int
main()
{
  int n;
  qsort(values, 6, sizeof(int), compare_reverse);
  for (n = 0; n < 6; n++) printf("%d ", values[n]);
  return 0;
}
```

which prints:

> `100 90 40 25 20 10`

---

Explanation: the line:

```
 CREATE_REVERSE(compare)
```

is expanded as

```
int compare_reverse(const void* a, const void* b) { return compare(b, a); }
```